# Unable to change font type in @kolkov/angular-editor

Tags: angular, editor, angular-ui-bootstrap, richtextbox, rich-text-editor

I have an issue with @kolkov/angular-editor to change font types. I found an issue with the tooltip class from bootstrap. If I removed the class it will work fine. With a tooltip class, it just disabled the font selection using the mouse. Other dropdown works fine.

Please find the below screenshot and code snippet.

[image]

[image]

Here, In first image I have used tooltip to show an error message at that time it won't me allow to chage the font types. If I remove the tooltip class it will work fine for me.

Please help me out of this issue.

We are using below configuration in out project.

```
angular: ~10.1.3
angular-edito : ^1.1.5
bootstrap: ^6.0.0
```

Comment: I tried downgrading the angular-editor version to 0.18.8, and the fonts started working fine. But for some reason it gave another error while submitting the form :/